# anoymous access and automatic mounting of a samba share from a windows system to a linux system

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, smb

I have most of my audio files on a system shared by most of the people in my family, and i'd like to be able to get them accessable to a headless linux box i control over smb. The share(s) in question are not on a share that requires authentication (and most examples assume so), and i'd like to have them automatically mounted, and accessable on boot.

I'd like to only use command line tools - so anything that has x dependancies is out, and shares should be accessable to any user on the system via a mount point

OS shouldn't matter, but the "fileserver" is a windows XP system, and i can access the shares without logging in, and the client is a ubuntu 10.04 lts system with a minimal CLI install.

Comment: Is the Windows XP "fileserver" a *Home* or a *Professional* variant?

Comment: professional. I can access the file share from another windows XP system without logging in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your Ubuntu 10.04 add a line to `/etc/fstab` telling your system to mount the remote WinXPProf share.

1. Create the mountpoint:
   `mkdir /mnt/winxp`.
2. Add the line to fstab:
   `echo "//windowsserver/sharename   /mnt/winxp   smbfs   auto" >>/etc/fstab`

This will auto-mount the remote share `sharename` on remote server `windowsserver` at boottime. Also, the commands `mount -a` or `mount /mnt/winxp` should re-mount that share, should the mounting have been lost for some reason.

For this to really work on WinXPPro, make sure the security settings [*] for the shared directory allows the *guest* user as well as the *everybody* group allow at least (depending on your requirements) read permissions.

---

[*] Right-click the foldername in explorer, select "Properties...". Go to the "Security" tab to add the "guest" user and the "everybody" group. Don't forget to click on the "Extended" button and make sure the NTFS permissions do allow the desired access for guest and everybody as well.